# How to add image to android app?? I reached till Imageview class but could not figure out further

Tags: android, imageview, uri

I am very new to Android development. 
I am trying to add an image to my Android application by code. I found [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nC_v0oKsnvU), but it is showing some drag and drop way to do it.
I want to do it by coding in my `onCreate` method.
I managed to do this:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
```

But could not figure out how to set the image-uri.
I tried the following:

```
iv.setImageURI(@"C:\Users\SONY\Downloads\slide.butcher.home.jpg");
```

with and without `@` but I think I need to pass an URI.

I tried to create an object of `android.net.Uri`, but it seems it can not be instantiated.

Comment: Check this [load-imageview-with-bitmap-from.html](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/load-imageview-with-bitmap-from.html)

Answer (score 1):

See the uri you have tried is wrong it is located on your **local file system**.. Instead try to push the image on the device's sdcard with the help of **DDMS** of eclipse..

Suppose you have pushed it on **/sdcard/your_image.jpg**. then in your code set your image path as

> imageView.setImageUri (Uri.parse("/sdcard/your_image.jpg"));

I m sure you will get it...

Comment: I m not sure abt your code but my code is working for me.. U should also try it

Comment: @Rashmi Using DDMS I manged to run the application. I have below code. super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello, Android");*/
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        //iv.setImageURI(@"C:\Users\SONY\Downloads\slide.butcher.home.jpg");
        iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse("/sdcard/slide.butcher.home.jpg"));
        setContentView(iv);                                        But i see only blank screen can not see image. What could be the reason?

Comment: So you are trying to see the image.. right??.. first step is to check weather you have image named  "slide.butcher.home.jpg" in path /sdcard/ if not then push it.. and try again..

Answer (score 0):

ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(v);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);

Answer (score 0):

> iv.setImageURI(@"C:\Users\SONY\Downloads\slide.butcher.home.jpg");

You are trying pass Uri of image which is stored on your Computer!!!!

Copy that file on your device SD Card.
Suppose you copied it under `/sdcard/home.jpg`

Then use below code to display it in ImageView.

```
imageView.setImageUri(Uri.parse("/sdcard/home.jpg"));
```

Comment: Using DDMS I manged to run the application. I have below code. super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); /*TextView tv = new TextView(this); tv.setText("Hello, Android");*/ ImageView iv = new ImageView(this); //iv.setImageURI(@"C:\Users\SONY\Downloads\slide.butcher.home.jpg"); iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse("/sdcard/slide.butcher.home.jpg")); setContentView(iv); But i see only blank screen can not see image. What could be the reason?